# Comparing Hours in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

While querying data from a database I receive the hours a process is started and ended in two separate string fields for example start = "1100" and end = "+0200" which indicate it's hours of operation are from 11am-2am. What is the proper way to represent this in swift so that I can determine the amount of time left from the current time to the end time of the process.

**EDIT**:
I found an interesting way using the date formatter if I remove any possible prefix of + and use the below code it seems to work correctly; however, the date is not set is their a work around?

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("1340")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `NSDate` from components using `NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra` (there are other similar functions, look up `NSCalendar` for details). You will need to add some logic to determine if the 2AM is today or tomorrow etc.

Then you can compare two `NSDate` dates. To determine time left to the end you would probably use `NSDate` method `timeIntervalSinceDate`. You can also use `NSDateComponentsFormatter` to get the remaining time nicely formatted.

Comment: In the end I took the direction you said parsed the string converted to int and instead used the dateBySettingHour function with the current date. Thank you